# How to declare PromotedBuildParameterDefinition in Jenlins Job DSL?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

Can I somehow describe the Promoted Build Parameter via Job DSL? Google is silent.

[image]

API:

[image]

I tried:

```
parameters {
  PromotedBuildParameterDefinition('release', "${projectTitle}/Release", 'Approved', '')
}
```

But error:

> ERROR: (script, line 3) No signature of method:
> javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.BuildParametersContext.PromotedBuildParameterDefinition()
> is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String,
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl, java.lang.String,
> java.lang.String) values: [release, screambot/Release, Approved, ]

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Just need use `PromotedBuildParameterDefinition` starts in lowercase `promotedBuildParameterDefinition`.